# Set MySQL variables using JOOQ with user inputs securely

Tags: java, mysql, sql-injection, jooq

I'm trying to set a MySQL variable using JOOQ like this. `value` is an user input.

```
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
dslContext.execute("set @myvar :=" + value);
```

While this works as expected, I'm concerned about the possible SQL Injections allowed by executing plain SQL like this with user inputs. Is there a way in JOOQ to achieve the same thing with prepared statements or any other safer manner?

Comment: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/statement-type/ may be helpful

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand, Jooq by default use prepared statements and that article shows how to deviate from default configuration run static statements. It doesn't shed any light on the question at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the plain SQL templating API:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

E.g. if you're using a simple bind variable:

```
 dslContext.execute("set @myvar := ?", value);
```

Or, if you wish to use a more complex expression:

```
 dslContext.execute("set @myvar := {0}", DSL.val(value));
```

Behind the scenes, by default, jOOQ will always execute a prepared statement.